# Find duplicate object from one collection to another collection - using 2 arrays in knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

In knockout JS I want to find out 1st duplicate object from my collection and return that object as modal. I have to check for 1st duplicate object from first array aginst 2nd Array based on my condition. Tried _findWhere & _.Some & _.each nothing worked. Can someone help

Here -- MyMainModal is my Moda which will have multiple objects

```
      self.dupRecord= function (MyMainModal) {
        var Modaldata= ko.mapping.toJS(MyMainModal);
            return _.some(Modaldata, function (MD1) {
                return _.some(Modaldata, function (MD2) {
                    if ((MD1.ID!== MD2.Id) &&
                        (MD1.Name === MD2.name));                    
                });
            });
        };
```

Comment: What you probably need is _.intersection() http://underscorejs.org/#intersection

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information and/or refine your question a little? What does your data look like, and what do you want the resulting data to look like?

Answer (score 0):

How about incorporating the check for first duplicate into the mapping? Something like:

```
function Child(data) {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};
var model = {
  children: [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Billy'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Susy'
  }]
};
var mapping = {
  children: {
    key: function(data) {
      return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
    },
    create: function(options) {
      console.log('creating ' + options.data.name, options.parent);
      var newChild = new Child(options.data);
      if(options.parent.firstDuplicate() === undefined)
        options.parent.children().forEach(function(child) {
          if(child.name() === newChild.name())
            options.parent.firstDuplicate([child, newChild]);
        });
      return newChild;
    },
    update: function(options) {
      console.log(' updating ' + options.data.name);
      return options.target;
    }
  }
};

var vm = {
  children: ko.observableArray(),
  firstDuplicate: ko.observable()
};
ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mapping, vm);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

model.children.push({
  id: 3,
  name: 'Billy'
});
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('--remapping--');
  ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mapping, vm);
}, 2000);
```

I read that as, "if we're not updating the record, potentially set the first duplicate." Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ge1abt6a/